# sql select all if column has only two particular values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, foreign-keys, inner-join

```
orders (
  o_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  o_status TINYINT,
  o_description VARCHAR(50),
)

orders_products (
  op_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  op_order_id INT(11),
  op_product_id INT(11),
  op_price DECIMAL(19, 2),
)
```

How to select all orders that have ONLY products with id = 1 and id = 2.

Thank you and sorry from my English...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways to get the desired result, this utilizes conditional aggregation:

```
select *
from orders 
where o_id in
 (
   select op_order_id 
   from orders_products
   having count(case when op_product_id = 1 then 1 end) > 0 -- at least one row with 1
      and count(case when op_product_id = 2 then 1 end) > 0 -- at least one row with 2
      and count(case when op_product_id not in (1,2) then 1 end) = 0 -- no other value 
 )
```

Depending on indexes/selectivity `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS` might be faster:

```
select o_id
from orders as o
where exists (select * 
              from orders_products as op
              where op.op_order_id = o.o_id 
                and op.op_product_id = 1)  -- at least one row with 1
  and exists (select * 
              from orders_products as op
              where op.op_order_id = o.o_id 
                and op.op_product_id = 2)  -- at least one row with 2
  and not exists (select * 
                  from orders_products as op
                  where op.op_order_id = o.o_id 
                    and op.op_product_id not in (1,2))  -- no other value
```

Comment: @Савостьянов Максим: The 1st query doesn't work? It's the same as Gordon Linoff's, just using Standard SQL syntax instead of proprietary MySQL

Answer (score 2):

You could first find all the distinct order and product combination for product 1 or 2 or both, and then look for orders that have both.

```
create table orders (o_id INT);
create table orders_products (op_order_id INT(11), op_product_id INT(11));

insert into orders values (1), (2);
insert into orders_products values (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2);

select o_id from (
  select distinct o_id, op_product_id
  from orders o
  inner join orders_products op on op.op_order_id = o.o_id
  where op.op_product_id in (1,2)
) main
group by o_id 
having count(*) = 2

Result:
1
```

Another way to write the query could be like this:

```
select o_id
from orders o
where exists (select 1 from orders_products where op_order_id = o.o_id and op_product_id = 1)
and exists (select 1 from orders_products where op_order_id = o.o_id and op_product_id = 2)
```

Comment: It works, thank you for your response. Where i can find some information about operator 'main' ?

Comment: It is not an operator. It is just an alias. Since I used a subquery, I had to give it some name. I just called it main. You can call it whatever valid name you like. For example: `select firstname from (select * from employees where age = 10)` may not work because `(select ... age = 10)` is a subquery without a tablename. Instead of tablename, we provide an alias to make subquery `proper` like this `select firstname from (select * from employees where age = 10) emps`, where `emps` is just an alias

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using aggregation and `having`:

```
select order_id
from order_products op
group by order_id
having sum(product_id = 1) > 0 and
       sum(product_id = 2) > 0 and
       sum(product_id not in (1, 2)) = 0;
```

If you want additional information about the order, then just join in the `orders` table.

Your question is what I call a "set-within-set" query . . . looking for patterns in a hierarchy (that is products within an order).  There are several ways to solve this, but the `having` clause turns out to be quite general.